I don't understand how difference of vectors work {HOMEWORK}
So in the picture we have vectors u and v. Our goal is to find  $v−u$

From what I know, the subtraction of vectors is just reversing the direction of the $2^{nd}$ vector & then finding the connecting vector.
Here is a (poor) drawing of what I think the resulting vector should look like :

My four options on what the resulting vector is are as follows:


As can be seen, none of the four vectors I am being given the option of choosing look remotely like what I would expect the resulting vector to look like.
I expect it to being going northwest but all the four vector options are going northeast. What am I not understanding here?

Hint: when adding vectors that are anchored at the same point, you don't form a triangle....

For a different question, how would you find the vector sum $v+u$?

@peterwhy I flip vector U so the head is touching the tail, then I make a vector from the head of V to the tail of U I believe.

Note: $\vec{v}-\vec{u} = \vec{v}+(-\vec{u})$. Incidentally, you seem to have visualized $-\vec{u}-\vec{v}$, but it's hard for me to tell for sure.

Parallelogram way will give the Solution.


Ah I see I forgot to move the -u vector so that the tail and head would touch. Very nice trick by the way!

My favorite way to think about vector subtraction is to note that
$$\vec u +(\vec v -\vec u)=\vec v$$
so to find $\vec v -\vec u$ I just think "well, I'm going to start with $\vec u$, add something, and  I want to end up at the end of $\vec v$", so I start at the end of $\vec u$ and then draw a vector that ends at the end of $\vec v$.
In your case you can see that answer d) is the only one that is even pointing in the right direction, and the slope looks good too. Obviously you'd have to check more precisely if the choices were more similar, but in this case it's easy.
